# Android displaying pop-up message or animation on button click

Tags: android, animation, button, message

I am really new to android programming, and I'm stuck with a really small problem in my app. The (very simple) app is almost ready, its just that there is a button and when it is clicked, I want the user to get a response in the form of either a message or some animation so that the user can feel that the app has registered the button click. I've been looking up and trying stackoverflow and other tutorials but to no avail. I just want some kind of a response when the button is clicked, so that the user doesn't feel confused about whether the app is working or not. Any help will be greatly appreciated!! Here's the code below:-

The XML file:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:background="#d1000000">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:id="@+id/Hinglishbutton"
        android:background="#cfa16cff"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:onClick="buttonHandler"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#a5fafbf9"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="71dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Welcome to Hinglish :)"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#a5fafbf9"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hinglish lets you add Hindi words to your predictive dictionary thus enabling a richer typing experience!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#a5fafbf9"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click the button once, minimize Hinglish and go grab a coffee. You will now be able to type hindi words without autocorrect converting them to junk english!"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#a5fafbf9"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Hosting this app costs money! To pitch in, contact the developer at spandan.madan@gmail.com :) :)"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textColor="#a5fafbf9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The myActivity.java file:-

```
   package com.example.spandanmadan1.hinglish;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        Button bsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hinglishbutton);

        bsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for using Hinglish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hindislang);
                BufferedReader bfr = null;
                try {
                    bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                        UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getApplicationContext(), line, 1, "", null);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a new project, used your xml and in the buttonHandler function I gave the toast as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}

public void buttonHandler(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for using Hinglish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This works. The Toast : "Thank you for using Hinglish" was displayed on screen.

Comment: Hi aashima, thanks for your reply.Thanks to your reply, I've figured out what the problem is. The moment I comment out the while loop in my code, the toast works. So now it remains to be seen how I can make them both work together! :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Upvoted! the problem is that the loop is running on the UI thread. Apparently I will have to use AsyncTask to run the loop in background and leave the UI thread free to display the toast :)

Comment: I've upvoted you, it won't reflect yet as my total reputation is < 15

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"<Your message to the User>",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The message will be shown when you click the button.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but its not working! Do I need to make I've updated the code above to show the new java file! Please take a look at it :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but check it out.
You've given:
    android:onClick="buttonHandler"

ie. this is the function expected to run when your button is clicked. Why don't you give the toast inside buttonHandler(View view)?

Or, remove onClick property from your xml and try again..

Comment: Hi! i just tried both the things -
1) created the buttonHandler function and executed it using the andoid:onClick=buttonHandler
2)remove android:onClick and put the toast command in the protected void onCreate()
Both aren't working :(